# Remove node_access check from content revisions view

Tags: 7, views

For the 'content' Views one can simply check tickbox 'Disable access checks' in UI under Advanced => Query, and the View returns all the records regardless of the node_access check.

However, in the 'content revisions' Views this tickbox is not available.

How can I make 'content revisions' Views to bypass the access_check?

Answer (score 1):

In the `hook_views_query_alter` is possible to alter the query tags. Unfortunately, the method tag_remove is not present, but the `$tags` variable is public, which allows us to do:

```
function yourmodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

    // Disable Node Access check for myview
    if ($view->name == 'myview') {
        $view->query->tags = [];
    }
}
```

I hope this will help somebody who needs unrestricted Views (e.g. for Services).